# How to automatically delete a Django Many-to-Many model entity once it no longer has any relations?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have two models, `Record` and `Tag`. They have a Many-to-Many relationship. `Tags` also has a Many-to-Many relationship with a third model, `Set`.

I'm using Django Rest Framework and the model serializer for `Tag` looks like this:

```py
class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    usage_count = serializers.IntegerField(
        source="record_set.count", read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = ("name", "usage_count")
```

What I want to achieve now is that once `usage_count` is `0`, i.e. a `Tag` is no longer related to any `Record`, it is automatically deleted.

The only reliable approach I could come up with is a cronjob that checks for Tags with such criteria and deletes them, as neither casecades nor any sort of delete "hooks" seem to do the trick.

Is there a way to achieve this with an approach that is more elegant than a  cronjob?

Comment: did you tried to use signal  after you save the tag if usage_count =0 then delete the related Sets? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/signals/#post-save

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this logic within the `Tag` model:

```py
class Tag(models.MOdel):
   # example of your fields..
   name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
   record = models.ManyToManyField(Record)

   def __str__(self):
      return str(self.name)

   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
      # example...

      if self.record.exists():
          # delete object if there 
          # - is no record.
          self.delete()
      else:
          return super(Tag, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Using signals:

```py
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

__all__ = ['check_delete_condition']

@receiver(post_save, sender="yourapp.Tag")
def check_delete_condition(instance, raw, created, using, updatefields, **kwargs):
    if instance.record.exists():
        instance.delete()
```